# Can windows calculator convert decimal fractions to binary?

Tags: windows-7, calculator

Suppose I have a fractional decimal number like 0.21

Can the windows calculator convert that to binary?

If I try to type in 0.21 while in programmer mode, it doesn't respond to the decimal point. It's like I can't type in a decimal point in programmer mode.. And I can't type a binary point in programmer mode either when I select binary within programmer mode. The 'point' seems to be disabled.

I am using windows 7. I don't know if this has been enabled in windows 10?

**Added**
Or how about a simpler example like 2.5 or 5.125 So, a fractional part that can be represented in binary?   So for 2.5 that calc should show 010.10  or 1.10*2^3.  Or for 5.125 the calc should show 0101.001 or 1.01001*2^5  Can the windows calculator show that?

Comment: This is because you cannot represent fractions in binary.

Comment: Not entirely correct. You can, but Windows calculator doesn't show. When we see a number, say `123`, we don't even think this way, but in reality, the number can be broken down into `1*10^2 + 2*10^1 + 10^0`, by the same logic, `123.45` is `1*10^2 + 2*10^1 + 3*10^0 + 4*10^(-1) + 5*10^(-2)`. The exact same thing happens with the binary math, except you only have 2 digits (represented by `0` and `1`) and the base of the system is `2`, not `10`. So `0.21` could be viewed as `0.0011010111` which is approximated as `0.209961`, I only did 10 binary digits, IEEE-754 standard specifies a lot more...

Comment: @nurchi You mean that Keltari is not  correct.  You're replying to Keltari not to me, so please write AT Keltari at the start of your comment, so it's clear you were referring to him and not to me

Comment: Seems like I cannot edit my comment anymore, but yes, I was referring to @Keltari's comment, not the question itself.

Comment: @Keltari no,  and no, you can't cover the about in your profile with binary and not know that it's possible to represent fractions with binary

Answer (score 1):

So the way fractions are represented in memory is according to the IEEE-754 standard for floating point numbers.

A number as simple as decimal 123 when stored as floating point number (e.g. 123.0) is actually stored as `1.921875 * 2^6 = 1.921875 * 64`

Think of this as a scientific notation, which is `a * 10^b`, where a must be [1, 10) (meaning from 1.0 up to, but not including 10, e.g. 9.999...8)

Your number `0.21` is stored in memory as `1.6799999475479126 * 2^(-3)` which is equivalent to `0.20999999344348907470703125` (windows calculator shows this as `0.209999993443489075` when calculating manually)

Any calculator that utilises this standard will store numbers in the same format (if it doesn't, excluding different endianness, it probably has a different way of storing floating point numbers, so when passing values from one piece of software/hardware to another, translation must happen, but this is a different topic altogether).

Now, to answer your question, while Windows calculator stores the numbers in this form, it hasn't been designed to show you the intermediate/raw values in the memory. If you really felt like it, you could use a memory viewing tool and spy on values as you type them in the calculator, but again, that is a different topic...

Check out https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html to have an idea of how the floating point numbers are stored and represented.

Comment: I notice this website gives a binary string for it, http://decimal-to-binary.com/decimal-to-binary-converter-online.html?id=2251  But it also an approxiation 'cos its string of 0.00110101110  is 1/8 + 1/16 + 1/64 + 1/256 + 1/512 + 1/1024 = (128/1024+64/1024+16/1024+4/1024+2/1024+1/1024)= 215/2014 = 0.2099609375  which is even less accurate than the approximation you gave.

Answer (score 1):

@Keltari Generally, fraction value CAN be represented in binary, using kind of "binary point" (counterpart of decimal point). In fact, that is how real/double numbers are represented in computers (although usually binary point position is stored, instead of the "point character"). But remember: not all decimal fractions can be represented in binary form *exactly* - some rounding must be applied then, especially if only limited count of bits can be used (which is always true in real computer science world).

Unfortunatelly, windows calculator in programmer's mode operate on integer values only. A workaround to achieve your goal is like this:

1. In standard mode enter a decimal number (can be fractional) to convert, e.g. <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>
2. Multiply it by 2 (keys: <kbd>*</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd>)
3. Repeat step 2 (pressing <kbd>=</kbd> key alone, again and again), until you receive number which is integer - or very close to integer (see remark below).

   **IMPORTANT!** Remember, how many times you multiplied initial value by 2 (in step 2 and repeated 3).
4. Switch to programmer's mode and enter value received after step 3, rounded to integer (unfortunately, that is not done automatically when switching mode, at least in Windows 10's Calculator app).
5. The binary representation of the integer number is shown. Imagine, the binary point is on the most right (after last binary digit). Then, move it left by as many positions as you have done multiplying in step 2 and 3. Add leading 0's as needed.

Example:

- Original value: `0.21`
- Multiply it by 2 ten times - you get `215,04`. Assuming that it is close enough to an integer value (it is arbitrary decision!), you get the rounded integer of `215`
- Entering `215` in programmer's mode shows its binary representation: `11010111`
- Moving the binary point 10 places left, gives: `.0011010111`

Remark: As I mentioned earlier, not all decimal fraction values can be represented *exactly* in binary form, so sometimes you must decide, what precision (approximation) satisfy your needs. In the example above, I assumed that rounding 215,04 to 215 is comparatively small "error" (below 1/5000), so 10 bits was enough to represent the original number. If I needed greater precision, I would make multiplying by 2 not ten, but maybe twenty times (result: `220200,96` rounded to `220201` as an integer) and would get 20-bits binary representation `.00110101110000101001` (with "error" below 1/5000000).

BTW Usually count of bits used to represent data in computers is power of 2 - 8, 16, 32, 64, sometimes 48, etc. In such a case, you can simply use faster "multipling by 2" method in the calculator, suggested by you in comment below (`*(2^n)`).

Comment: Very interesting.. a few observations.. A)step 2 can be sped up with the x^y button on the window calculator. in scientific mode. e.g. 0.21*2^30  The integer part of that number can then be converted to binary in the windows calculator.   B)Where you wrote "multiply it 10 times by 2" I think you meant multiply it by 2 ten times, / 10 times, multiply it by 2,  i.e. 2^10.

Comment: C)Interestingly I learnt a much slower method than your method, the method I learnt was each time you multiply it by two, if the number is <1 then write a 0 in your result string.  If the number is >= 1, you subtract one and write a 1 in your result string. .

Comment: @barlop 
ad. A) Yes, using x^y operation is much faster, and is usefull if you know in advance, how many bits you are going to use for binary representation (_y_ in the formula).
ad. B) Sorry for any misleading expressions - English is not my mothers' language :-) - edited as you suggested

Comment: Nice workaround, @AnSi

Comment: There is no need to write in your first sentence that fractions "CAN" be represented in binary. I know they can. The only person that said they can't is one commenter "nurchi". But an answer is assumed to be addressed to the person that asked the question - me. So there is no need to so emphatically state something in your first sentence that I already agree with. That entire first sentence is superfluous. I even mentioned "binary point" in my question so i'm well aware of it

Comment: Why did you make your first sentence "Generally, fraction value CAN be represented in binary, using kind of "binary point" (counterpart of decimal point)"     Nobody said they can't. And Why are you introducing the term "binary point" to me like I don't know it when I already know it and stated it in my question?

Comment: @barlop Yes, you are right, that first sentence is not in opposite to any of your statement in initial question - it's reply to @-Keltari comment. But I have too few "reputations" to be allowed to comment other's comments, so that was the only way to express my disagree. However, I should mention @-keltari to be clear - my fault (fixed in edited answer).

Answer (score 0):

No it can't.

Qalculate can though

[image]

Speedcrunch can too though it has a slightly funny way of displaying it. I mention speedcrunch 'cos I use it for some stuff.

speedcrunch displays hex like this (preceding the number by 0x)

[image]

[image]

And displays binary like this
(a bit unusual to show binary by preceding it with 0b but anyhow, you know it's not hex there because in settings..results format,  binary is selected.. and that with hex it has 0x and it has capitals for the hex digits)

[image]